# How can I model this behavior in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model, message

I want to develop a notification system with Django. So I have an button (and a count of unread messages), that show all messages to the user, so the counter returns to zero again. How can detect my database, that the user already has read the messages and reset the counter? I dont think that I can emulate this with forms, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the `django-notifications` package:
https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications

It does exactly what you want. 
It also comes with a [Live Updater Api](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications#live-updater-api) to keep the unread notification number in sync.

Comment: I will check if I'm able to use it. It's a bit confusing about of 4 main components

Comment: Do you mean `actor`, `verb`, `action`, and `target`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm relatively new in Django so I'm still learning about this. I was reading the documentation and seems to be the right answer. Are these four items relevant?

Comment: @jonango Did my answer help you? If so accept it, please.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you will have some view which will render page on which user of your site will be able to read the unread notifications. So I think you can simply add to notifications model bool field unread. This field is set up when there is new notification to `true`. After user render page with unread notifications this view simply change this filed to `false`. When you query using `where(ureaded==true)` for notifications one more time those will be avoided.

Comment: But, this works in real time? Can I handle this with POST method? After of rendering the page and normally for retrieving info, I have to use POST method, but I have used it before only in forms.